# How to rearrange a result set from a UNION query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that seems to be alphabetizing based on the text values of the Result Set.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT 'N/A' FROM [Games] UNION SELECT [Games].[Title] FROM Games;
```

The Result Set looks like this:

```
Final Fantasy VII
N / A
The Legend of Zelda
```

I would like the Result Set to look like this:

```
N / A
Final Fantasy VII
The Legend of Zelda
```

Where Final Fantasy VII and The Legend of Zelda are actual entries in the Games table and N / A is, of course, not.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the sort order explicitly  :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM ( SELECT 'N/A' AS Title, 1 AS ID  
       FROM [Games], 
       UNION 
       SELECT [Games].[Title], 2 
       FROM Games
     ) t
ORDER BY ID, Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query :

```
select * from 
(SELECT 'N/A' as title,0 as ord FROM [Games] 
UNION 
SELECT [Games].[Title],1 as ord FROM Games)a
order by ord,title
```

Comment: This is close, but it flips the order of the games. i.e. It shows N / A, Zelda, and then Final Fantasy

Comment: modified it..need to add one more column in order by clause and that is title

Comment: What is title in the order by? Nevermind, I gotchya,

Comment: title is the column name